# Modifying java/php

Tags: java, php, html, css, asp-classic

I want to modify this, because it only worked in .asp files, and now my document is in .php

But this script,, it's annoying me.
What i want to do is, calculating how many days has gone since year 1858 month 3 and day 21
Until now, and ofc it needs to say "Today the union has existed for "year" & "month" & days"

Hope u can help!

```
<div id="idag" align="center"><p>I dag har foreningen eksisteret i 
<%=DateDiff("yyyy",#1858-03-21#,#2014-01-01#)%>
 år og 
<% 'Noter at der er fratrukket 20 dage fra dage. Detta må korrigeres vid skudår!' %> 
<%=DateDiff("d",#2014-01-22#,now)%> dage</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need to get the difference between two dates - now and the given date and then format it into a sentence using php. The below should suffice. You'll get warnings if you don't have a timezone set, though, but I assume you have that covered.

Here's the [**PHPFiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/s4u-8wp) for a test run.

```
<?php

    $datetime1 = date_create('now');
    $datetime2 = date_create('1858-03-21');
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('Today the union has existed for %y years, %m months, and %d days.');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working, because what about "leap-year" the union has not existed for 155 and 10 months and some days, it has just turned 156 years? :)